# Expected identifier or '(' - Xcode mistake

Tags: objective-c

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    struct label.text =
}
```

Whats the problem?
Why does Xcode say:
"Expected identifier or '('?"

Comment: Assuming `label` is a member of whatever class implements this action, you don't need that `struct` keyword before `label.text =`.  After that, of course, the compiler will want you to have something on the right hand side of the equals sign.

Comment: But it says: "You must add struct for using label" (or something like this)

Comment: I deleted "struct" but the problem is still there and now I have 2 warnings!

Comment: You still need to have label.text = SOMETHING.

Comment: Now I have: - (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    label.text = @Hello!
}

Comment: try @"Hello!"  you need the parentheses.

Comment: ok i did the parentheses but i still have 2warnings!! 1: expected identifier or ( and 2: must use struck tag to refer to type label!!! plz help

Comment: my actual code is:- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{label.text = @"Hello!"}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make a button and when someone clicks on it the label text changes to "hello!"

Comment: which answer?:o @Douglas

Comment: It's coming.  Hold on.

Comment: Not related to the Xcode IDE itself

Comment: what is the `struct` keyword for...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you have hooked up your button correctly, are you using storyboards?  If you are just drag a button and a label out to the storyboard.  Open the assistant editor, it's a button that looks like a tux up in the right hand corner.  You need to declare what your items will do.  In the assistant open your .h file.  Control drag from the label to the .h and select outlet.  Call it label it you wish.  Then control drag from the button and select action.  Call that button if you wish.  This is what your .h file should look like.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then in your .m file you should make it look like.

```
import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

_label.text = @"Hello";
}
@end
```

I did this and when I touched the button the text changed from label to Hello.  You also forgot the colon at the end.

Comment: You might also want to do some of the tutorials on Ray Wenderlich's site.  Very useful.

Comment: but in my m file it says that the (at)end is missing but its there?!

Comment: In the .m file there should be an (at)end after the (at)interface.  Then there should also be another (at)end after the (at)implementation.  Just make sure they are both there.

Comment: @RonTheHedgehog, Did you get it to work?  And thanks for the check!  Welcome to stackoverflow, I will tell you now it is addictive!!

Comment: Now i have no issues and its same codes like yours but when i go to the simulator and click on the button it don't changes!:(

Comment: @RonTheHedgehog, that could be because you did not link the button up with the action.  Use the assistant, have both story board open and your .h file.  Control drag from your button to the IBAction.  Also, make sure that you do the same for the label, but control drag from the label to the (at)property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to your resources where you learned Objective-C and Cocoa, what you have is wrong in fundamental ways that show you don't understand the language at all

```
struct label.text =
```

This looks like just random tokens.

Comment: I got this code from a tutorial. But in the tutorial it don't shows the warning.

Comment: Then I would find another tutorial, this is just gibberish

Answer (score 0):

It looks like XCode is simply getting confused because the syntax of your statement is wrong. It looks like the line `struct label.text =` is trying to define a variable of type `struct` with the name `label.text`.

In Objective-C, the dot operator lets you access a method or property of an object. Trying to do this in the name of the variable doesn't make sense.